# Exception class required for the event ibm messaging queue timeout

Tags: ibm-mq

I am new to the messaging queue implementation.

I have implemented IBM messaging queue(MQ) in my application.

Problem statement:

When this MQ is not able to handle certain number of messages MQ throws timeout exception.

Due to a technical limitation of my system I am unable to catch the exact exception class.

Means that I simply declare catch(Exception e) ..but I would like to know exactly which exception class should be use to handle timeout error.

Comment: Which version of MQ client are you using?  Is this Java or JMS?  Can you provide some of your source code that shows where the error is happening?  When you say "MQ is not able to handle certain number of messages" that it throws a timeout exception, do you mean a specific queue becomes full?  Normally this would throw a queue full error (MQRC_Q_FULL 2053) not a timeout.

Comment: Post sample code and point out which line of code you think is problematic

Comment: I asked many questions,  unfortunately you answered the least helpful to provide assistance.   When you can respond to the rest let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some MQ training or you need to do a lot of reading on MQ.

There is no such thing as a timeout on an MQPUT.  I would say you have some poorly written code and you are confusing MQ with your poorly written code.  Are you logging ALL interactions?

If your code is Java/JMS then you should have the following exception:

```
catch (JMSException e)
{
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   if (e != null)
      System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
}
```

If your code is plain Java then you should have the following exception:

```
catch (MQException e)
{
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   System.err.println("CC = " + e.completionCode + " : RC = " + e.reasonCode + " [" + MQConstants.lookup(e.reasonCode, "MQRC_.*") +"]");
}
```

Comment: @RockingDev Where in the program does it fail?

Comment: Then use Roger's suggested "Java/JMS" code to capture the proper exception.  You still never answered the question of what version the jar files are from.  You can get this with the command `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version` on unix, or on windows rename the `.jar` to a `.zip` and look inside of it as a compressed folder to view the same file and information above.

Comment: @RockingDev I copied & pasted 2 pieces of code, just wrap the whole thing with "if (e != null)".  The simple way to find out the MQ JAR version is to just run the JAR.  i.e. `java -jar com.ibm.mq.jar` or `java -jar com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`